# where are all the places C++ searches for includes?

Tags: c++, include, include-path

Is there a way to check all of the locations C++ searches for includes? I would like to understand why some includes are found and others are not.

EDIT: Platform is Linux, g++

Comment: For many (most?) compilers, there are ways, but it will be compiler specific (e.g., VC++ uses the contents of the `INCLUDE` environment variable).

Comment: It depends on the compiler of course.

Comment: platform? compiler? IDE?

Comment: On GCC you can add the option `-H` to show inclusions.

Comment: e.g. echo "#include <sys/types.h>" | gcc -E -x c -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is compiler-dependent: you pass the locations for the headers in angular brackets, and the headers in double quotes are expected to be at the path rooted at the location of the current file; compilers also let you specify additional locations for these files.

For example, `gcc` has two options - `-I` and `-i` for specifying locations of headers specified as `<header.h>` and `"header.h"`. If `-I` is not specified, the default locations of

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

are searched, as specified in [the `gcc` documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html).

Answer (score 0):

16.2 [cpp.include] defines this for C++; the language in C is pretty much the same.

`#include <header.h>` searches a set of implementation-defined locations for a "header" with that name. This "header" does not have to be a file; it can be something the compiler magically knows about.

`#include "header.h"` also searches a set of implementation-defined locations, but it looks for a file with the name "header.h". if that search fails, it treats the directive as `#include <header.h>`.

Many compilers implement the second search by looking in the "current directory", which for some compilers means the directory from which the compiler was launched, and for others means the directory in which the file containing the `#include` directive is located.

In general, you should us the quoted form for you headers; the angle brackets, because they don't require a file, should be left for the implementation to use. Not that using angle brackets for your own headers won't work, but it's anti-thematic.